# rails model save is not being committed, but no errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails

rails 3.2.8

I tried to create a simple polymorphic Log model as logable. The table has only one field, log and it was envisioned as just a timestamp and a short message would be appended to a has_one relation.

My problem is that after the record is created, I can't seem to get the message to append and save. Debugging shows it has be committed and the record is changed, but when it is reloaded it reverts to the original version. I've been looking at this way to long and it is time to see if anyone else sees something stupid.

Relevant parts of the models:

```
class Log < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :logable, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :logable_id, :log, :logable_type

  def set_log(entry)
    self.log << "\r\n#{Time.now.to_s} - #{entry}"
    self.save    
  end
end

class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :citizen_id, :commitment_id, :current_stage, :current_status
  has_one :log, :as => :logable

  def append_log(entry)
    if self.log.nil?
      self.build_log( :log => "#{Time.now.to_s} - Log Created")
      self.log.save
    end
    self.log.set_log(entry)
  end
end
```

Below is from the console log where I get a Candidate, look at the log (original created entry only), append a entry, show the changes made in the instance. Reload the log record and the changes are gone.

```
1.9.2-p136 :001 > c = Candidate.find(1)
  Candidate Load (15.1ms)  SELECT "candidates".* FROM "candidates" WHERE "candidates"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]

1.9.2-p136 :002 > c.log
  Log Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "logs".* FROM "logs" WHERE "logs"."logable_id" = 1 AND "logs"."logable_type" = 'Candidate' LIMIT 1
 => #<Log id: 1, logable_id: 1, logable_type: "Candidate", log: "2012-11-16 15:23:49 -0600 - Log Created", created_at: "2012-11-16 21:23:49", updated_at: "2012-11-16 21:23:49"> 

1.9.2-p136 :003 > c.append_log("Add entry")
LOG BEFORE 2012-11-16 15:23:49 -0600 - Log Created
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
LOG APPENDED 2012-11-16 15:23:49 -0600 - Log Created
2012-11-16 16:05:53 -0600 - Add entry
NOTE Log field has been appended
 => nil 

1.9.2-p136 :004 > c.log
 => #<Log id: 1, logable_id: 1, logable_type: "Candidate", log: "2012-11-16 15:23:49 -0600 - Log Created\r\n2012-11-16...", created_at: "2012-11-16 21:23:49", updated_at: "2012-11-16 21:23:49">

NOTE Now reload the log record
1.9.2-p136 :005 > l = Log.find(1)
  Log Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "logs".* FROM "logs" WHERE "logs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
 => #<Log id: 1, logable_id: 1, logable_type: "Candidate", log: "2012-11-16 15:23:49 -0600 - Log Created", created_at: "2012-11-16 21:23:49", updated_at: "2012-11-16 21:23:49"> 
NOTE The add entry line is gone!
```

I don't know if this is a problem with the has_one relation, but even if I just call set_log with just the log record, at appears to append, but reloading does not have the changes.

Stumped Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you showing all of the rails log?  After you call `c.append_log` I would expect to see an `UPDATE` SQL log entry, but there isn't one.  That suggests that `self.save` in `set_log` is failing.  Spit out the `.errors` on `c.log` and see if a validation is failing...

Turns out it's because `<<` doesn't twiddle the dirty attribute bits.

Changing `<<` to `+=` should do the trick.

`self.log += "\r\n#{Time.now.to_s} - #{entry}"`

Comment: I've had error trapping on, tried save! and a bunch of other things. There are no errors (and no validations) Your are right that the update sql is not there, just the start transaction and commit. Almost appears that that field is not set to dirty.

Comment: Forgot that on creating a new record, the insert sql is there. Again, I've tried to save in the Candidate model and other things and appears I found a bug that does not make sense or I have an sqllite corruption

Comment: That's it... `<<` doesn't twiddle the dirty bits. Change it to use `+=`

Comment: Thank you. I discovered it about the same time and tried to answer my own question, but can't for 10 hours. The proposed post just use += and all worked.  If this a known error or limitation:-) Just wondered if I should post it somewhere?

Comment: @appleII717 Had the same problem - didn't see that it was solved right away. Come back and accept an answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

try to

```
self.save!
```

which should raise the error(s) if there are any

you can also raise your own exception or do magic like

```
if !self.save
  raise "attempt to save failed"
end
```

Comment: I've tried save! and had error trapping in, but no error.  self.errors show no messages.

Comment: I tried executing @object.save! but got the below exception ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved Exception: ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved. @object.errors does not show anything, I am still stuck at this situation

Comment: old post, but same here… how do you add those errors, in order to have them visible in `@object.errors` ?